# Is Satan's kingdom here on earth?

Tags: catholicism, creation, eschatology, satan, crucifixion

Reading Matthew 12:26

If Satan drives out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then can his kingdom stand?

I cant seem to pin point where is his kingdom? Evil men dont seem to be united?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three questions plus the question in the quote.
**Is Satan's kingdom here on earth?** Yes, the adversary is here on earth. He was cast out when Jesus was "snatched up to God and to his throne" (Rev 12:5). Most likely his  "Ascension into Heaven" (Acts 1:9-11) but possibly at his death on the Cross.

**I cant seem to pin point where is his kingdom?** Opposing the spirit is the Flesh (Gal 5:17) Therefore when serving the Flesh we also serve Satan. "..you are slaves of the one you obey.." (Romans 6:14-19).

These two questions work together.
**Evil men dont seem to be united?**
 
"**If Satan drives out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then can his kingdom stand?**" -Matthew 12:26

Singular: If a man hates himself and actively pursues damage to himself. How can he stay alive?

Married Couple: If the couple actively pursue damage to the relationship. How can the relationship survive?

Comment: I have down voted your question  because of your statement He was cast out when Jesus was "snatched up to God and to his throne" (Rev 12:5). Most likely his "Ascension into Heaven" (Acts 1:9-11) but possibly at his death on the Cross.                                                      That statement is in opposition to:     Luke 10:18  And he said unto them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven.

Comment: pardon my error I meant to say your answer

Comment: Not offended, instead I'm excited that maybe together we can figure out when this happened then. I wasn't thinking of the Luke account. There was a reason that I posted that though. Rev 12:9 accounts for Satan being tossed out of Heaven. To summarize Rev 12:5-9 Jesus Born; Prediction he would rule; Was Snatched to God; Mary fled for 3.5 years; War in Heaven; Satan hurled to earth. So this is our time line. If we consider his snatching at his birth, and the 3.5 years the fleeing from King Herod to Egypt (Matthew 2:13). Been having trouble placing the event of the 3.5 years. What do you think?

Comment: @ Only he is good If what you are looking for is when Satan was cast out of Heaven, this is my idea of when based on the Scriptures that I know; 
Isaiah 14:12 How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations! Luke 10:18 And he said unto them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven. If Satan was cast to the ground, it must be between Genesis 1:1 and Genesis 3:1

Comment: Ok I see your logic. So to restate for my understanding, How could Satan be in the Garden unless he had already fallen out of heaven? Answer from that perspective: He must have already fallen, otherwise he would have not been there to convince Eve. This leads to another question though. Why was he cast out of heaven when he has not yet received his punishment? (Gen 3:14-15). I do hope you can help me figure this out, Thank you so much Cecil.

Comment: @ Only he is good The punishment of Genesis 3:14 and 15 is of the Serpent, and not Satan, Satan entered the Serpent just as he entered Judas Iscariot in:  ( Luke 22:3  Then entered Satan into Judas surnamed Iscariot, being of the number of the twelve.) Satan was  ejected from Heaven because of his rebellion against God:  (Revelation  12:7 through 9  And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels, And prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven. Continued in next comment

Comment: And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.  Satan was judged at the cross and his punishment will begin in: 
(Rev 20:10  And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever.)

Comment: Now if your agreeing with me that Satan was cast upon the earth in Rev 12:7-9 as you have suggested in your last two posts, please read earlier in Revelations 12:5-6. See that Rev 12:7 starts with the word "Then" showing that it occurs after. What is he being cast down after? The events of Revelations 12:5-6. The occurrence that is spoken of in Revelations 12:5 is that of Jesus being snatched away, and this occurred directly after it talks of his birth. So the snatching happened between his conception to his ascension. I feel more towards at his death now because of (Rev 12:10-12).

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a long look at the Scriptures around your referenced Scripture:

Matthew 12:25 through 28 KJV

> 25  And Jesus knew their thoughts, and said unto them, Every kingdom divided against itself is brought to desolation; and every city or house divided against itself shall not stand:
>
> 26  And if Satan cast out Satan, he is divided against himself; how shall then his kingdom stand?
>
> 27  And if I by Beelzebub cast out devils, by whom do your children cast them out? therefore they shall be your judges.
>
> 28  But if I cast out devils by the Spirit of God, then the kingdom of God is come unto you.

and see if Jesus was actually saying that Satan had a Kingdom to begin with. What Jesus was retorting to was the verse preceding this retort (Matthew 12:24):

But when the Pharisees heard it, they said, This fellow doth not cast out devils, but by Beelzebub the prince of the devils.

Jesus was incensed by their claim that he was getting his power to do these miracles from Satan, and his angry retort was meant to marginalize them.

In verses 26 and 27 He is belittling them by:

1. saying that If Satan is ruining his own plans, If He had a Kingdom by fighting against himself he would be destroying his own Kingdom.
2. Jesus is saying and if as you say I am getting my power from Satan, where are your people getting their power from?

The last stone he casts is in verse 28 where he tells them knowing what I have just told you my power must come from another source. and if my source is God then you have just seen the Kingdom of God.

Here are some other Scriptures concerning Satan's supposed power which you may find will help you in understanding Satan. Please remember that Jesus himself said that Satan was a liar and the father of lies.

Matthew 4:1-11  KJV

> Again, the devil taketh him up into an exceeding high mountain, and sheweth him all the kingdoms of the world, and the glory of them; And saith unto him, All these things will I give thee, if thou wilt fall down and worship me.

Mark 3:22-26  KJV

> And the scribes which came down from Jerusalem said, He hath Beelzebub, and by the prince of the devils casteth he out devils. And he called them [unto him], and said unto them in parables, How can Satan cast out Satan? And if a kingdom be divided against itself, that kingdom cannot stand. And if a house be divided against itself, that house cannot stand. And if Satan rise up against himself, and be divided, he cannot stand, but hath an end.

In This Scripture what Jesus is pointing to is that if what they were claiming were true then Satan does not have the power of God since he could not do what they claimed and be eternal.

Revelation 2:13  KJV

> I know thy works, and where thou dwellest, [even] where Satan's seat [is]: and thou holdest fast my name, and hast not denied my faith, even in those days wherein Antipas [was] my faithful martyr, who was slain among you, where Satan dwelleth.

Revelation 12:9-12  KJV

> Therefore rejoice, [ye] heavens, and ye that dwell in them. Woe to the inhabiters of the earth and of the sea! for the devil is come down unto you, having great wrath, because he knoweth that he hath but a short time.

Revelation 3:9  KJV

> Behold, I will make them of the synagogue of Satan, which say they are Jews, and are not, but do lie; behold, I will make them to come and worship before thy feet, and to know that I have loved thee.

Revelation 12:9-12  KJV

> Therefore rejoice, [ye] heavens, and ye that dwell in them. Woe to the inhabiters of the earth and of the sea! for the devil is come down unto you, having great wrath, because he knoweth that he hath but a short time.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about spiritual world. How it is reflected within humanity? How it manifests? How a spiritual world stands?

To understand how a man can become evil man, or a good man, I will quote from Holy Tradition of Orthodoxy, where many mysteries about humanity and God where revealed to us through Holy Spirit and His servants. (http://tzarlazar.tripod.com)

> [CHAPTER FOUR](http://tzarlazar.tripod.com/lazar04.htm) ...Man is wondrously composed of body, soul, and
>   spirit. The spirit is the mover and the lord of the whole of man's
>   being. As the spirit is, so will the movements of the soul and body
>   be. As the spirit is, so also is the man. The spirit moves the soul,
>   and the soul the body. 'It is the spirit that gives life, the flesh is
>   of no avail.' (John 6). Even the circles of the angelic host in the
>   heavenly kingdom live and are moved only by the Spirit of God. From
>   that Spirit there springs forth for us angels those four streams of
>   sweetness: truth, love, life, and joy. In this same manner the
>   progenitor of your race also lived and was moved by the Spirit of God,
>   similar to us angels.
>
> "When, however, he insanely departed from righteousness and heavenly
>   Love, a fundamental transformation took place in him. In appearance he
>   remained the same; nevertheless an essential change occurred within
>   him. To this day little is known in the world about this
>   transformation. It is one of the strangest, quietest, most consecrated
>   mysteries.  The fundamental transformation lay in this: the insulted
>   Creator pulled His Holy Spirit out of man, and left man alone with his
>   created soul and natural spirit. With this natural spirit, which is
>   created and not inspired by God, fallen man was condemned "to eat
>   bread in the sweat of his face" (Gen. 3), like the ants and the
>   bees and the beasts. Thus man degenerated into an animal, the lord
>   became the peer of his servants, the king became equal to his
>   subjects. Man the god became man the animal. But this is not the worst
>   part. For the animals are in their own state wondrous and beautiful.
>   What is the worst part is that man the animal quickly tumbled down
>   into man the demon, of his own free will. Of his own free will, after
>   having exchanged the Holy Spirit for an unclean vessel, he also threw
>   away his natural, created spirit and accepted into himself a third
>   spirit — the unclean spirit, the spirit of falling away from God and
>   struggling against God, the spirit of the angels of hell. For when man
>   lost the Holy Spirit, he was placed at a crossroads, where his natural
>   created spirit is in control, and where two opposite spirits meet: the
>   spirit of light and the spirit of darkness, the Spirit of God and the
>   spirit of hell. 
>        "At this crossroads, where the natural spirit is in control and where the two opposing spirits are blowing, many people turn their
>   face to the spirit of darkness and death, while there are only a few
>   who turn their face toward God. To these latter our gracious God has
>   again given His Holy Spirit. These are those amazing righteous people,
>   to whom the promise and the prophesied salvation have been given. As
>   it has been given to them so also will it be given through them to
>   every future generation of mankind, so long as it remains on the
>   crossroads facing towards the God of life. 
>        "For thousands of years they have been the only man-gods in the midst of the man-animals and, what is worse, man-demons. They have
>   been called gods and sons of God, not because of their mortal flesh or
>   their natural soul and spirit, but because of the Holy Spirit of God,
>   which has been given to them again, and because at the crossroads of
>   the spirits their face has been turned, with faith and reverence,
>   towards the Holy Spirit of God. Because of this God has breathed His
>   Spirit from Himself into them, and thus they have been made worthy to
>   be called gods and sons of God. ...

With this understanding we can pin point how the kingdom of Satan stands.
As an example think about 2 men driven by the same evil spirit. They maybe want to hurt themselves or to kill each other, in appearance they are not united but in spirit they are the similar, exercising the same activity. They are bearers of the same evil spirit, and they potentially contaminate with the same spirit people around them which they contact to .. the hate, the greedy, the deprivation, the anger, the proud etc are manifestations of the same evil spirit. 
When you observe this around you and inside you, over and over, you can realize in which Kingdom you or people around you are living and how this Kingdom stands.